How to make concentric half-circles in Blender 3.4.1
I'm creating a model of a city street layout. The city has straight streets and semicircular avenues; the streets are set up, but the avenues are proving difficult. Currently, I'm trying to use a Bezier curve with either an array modifier or geometry nodes. Neither is working properly: scaling on the array gives increasing spacing between avenues, and the geometry node methods I've found turn the avenues into full circles. How do I create multiple semicircles with the same centre and uniform spacing?

Sorry, you have to explain a bit more how you want to get the avenues placed somewhere... because there are way to create semi-circular shapes, the question is what criteria are given that they have to fulfill... for example, given start and end points to connect with something, the center and radius or anything like that?

Do you have a question we can answer? Could you edit your post and rephrase it to read like a clear question with a specific issue we can solve?

If the center of an arc is in origin, scaling coordinates of points on the arc will move them all proportionally away from the origin, maintaining the shape, and therefore allowing to apply different scaling for duplicates - you can pass Index through Map Range node to easily control a linear distribution of scale:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

I had to experiment a fair bit, but I got it working. Thank you very much.
